# Git maintenance logs

Tags: git, macos, logging, git-maintenance

I am using the [git-maintenance](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-maintenance) feature.

It is hopefully working well, but I would like to be able to check logs to make sure of that. Are there any such logs? Where?

I'm particularly interested in the answer for macOS. I have checked the `.plist` config files, but they do not mention any log files. I have searched in the `console` app, but found nothing.

Comment: `git maintenance` is new and somewhat experimental (not sure why it's not marked with numerous warnings to that effect). The macOS support is *very* new and I believe you must build Git from source to get it. It should read and write these files as described, but logging probably still goes to plain files in the `.git` directory at this point.

Comment: @torek I could not find any relevant logs in the `.git` directory, not even in the `logs` folder.

Comment: The only thing `git gc` ever seemed to log was a complaint that there were too many loose objects and that it needed to be run without `--auto`. I think this went to `.git/gc.log` or similar.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [source code](http://github.com/git/git/blob/cefe983a320c03d7843ac78e73bd513a27806845/builtin/gc.c), it doesn't seem like `maintenance` is doing any logging of its own. Instead, it delegates work to the existing functions in `gc.c`.

From the initial commit [`2057d750` (Sep 17, 2020)](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2057d75038541cd16debb1c55f3f897fd244965c):

> For now, the 'maintenance' builtin is a thin shim over the 'gc' builtin.
> In fact, the only option is the '--auto' toggle, which is handed
> directly to the 'gc' builtin. The current change is isolated to this
> simple operation to prevent more interesting logic from being lost in
> all of the boilerplate of adding a new builtin.
>
> Use existing builtin/gc.c file because we want to share code between the
> two builtins. It is possible that we will have 'maintenance' replace the
> 'gc' builtin entirely at some point, leaving 'git gc' as an alias for
> some specific arguments to 'git maintenance run'.

The functionality of `git-maintenance` is indeed implemented in `gc.c` as a series of functions whose names start with `maintenance_`.